# Where to store and how to access different DPI images on Android in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

For Xamarin.Android it's simple as it only involves 1 platform (and resources are stored in `Projectname.Android/Resources/mipmap-{hdpi|mdpi|xhdpi...}`). For Xamarin.Forms on the other hand the code refers to single resources/images and as far as they work on different platforms (the same code and the same resources), I can't find a way to provide resources for different resolutions to be automatically picked up based on the screen size/dpi?

Is there a way to achieve that in common Xamarin.Forms project or shall I go and handle it in platform-specific projects' (Android, iOS) code?

Comment: Is it helpful for you ?

Answer (score 1):

The best thing so far is this plugin [Resizetizer](https://github.com/Redth/ResizetizerNT). You can have all your images in shared project and all images are generated during build time for all platforms (don't worry about the build time, it is similar to incremental build). This approach will also be in .NET Maui which will be launched with .NET 6.

There is also [super nice video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/XamarinShow/Cross-platform-Images-Simplified-with-ResizetizerNT--The-Xamarin-Show) which really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

As Xamarin.Forms does not seem to support loading image resources from a mipmap folder at this time，you could put different dpi images into the `drawable` folder like (`Resources/drawable--{hdpi|mdpi|xhdpi...}`) like mipmap.Then it will pick up the image  based on the screen size/dpi automatically.